# Wordpress CSS: Page has no style

Tags: css, wordpress

I have this website http://yourehab.com/ and as you can see there are 2 version (German and English). The English version is ok, but if you click on the DE version the page has no style (CSS). How can i solve it?

Comment: Server does not find out css .. i checked in chrome it says 404 error for all styles and js .. fix by copying all the css files from the english site  and copy to german site  that it will be ok ..

Comment: i think check the urls thay are miss matched for 

english site you gave = http://yourehab.com/your_css_file_link 

for german site you gave = http://yourehab.com/de/your_css_file_link 

remove the /de/ from all the css in your german site will work fine

Comment: The problem is that all the CSS and JS files link to the `site.com/de/path/to/filename` but all resources are located in `site.com/path/to/filename`. Check the plugin settings or change the code to use site base url instead of subfolder.

Answer (score 1):

Which Translation Plugin are you using ?
I suppose you have hard-coded url links in your templates. Use 'plugins_url', 'get_template_directory_uri' for loading styles and js files.
If you choose the 'DE' in the url to be as a parameter at the end of the url -> ?lang=de, i suppose it will work. But you have to correct the hardcoded values. (There is an option in the plugin about that)

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. Please, add this kind of answer in the comment section.

Comment: This is mixed comment + answer :)